# javascript rounding by 500

Tags: javascript, rounding

how to round 17000595 to 17000500 with javascript?

Answer (score 13):

Here is the **formula**

- Divide it by 500,
- take its floor value
- and multiply it by 500 again.

**code is** -

```
Math.floor(17000595/500) * 500
```

Comment: thanks a bunch it woks!

Comment: Text says 'ceiling', code says `floor`, and maybe you could consider using `Math.round`, if you want, for example, 800 to be rounded up to 1000.

Comment: clearly floor is right if you look at the example in the question

Comment: @goleztrol corrected the formula description, Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: hello gurvinder & all can u help me also in how to do it with mysql query?

Comment: @DeviSiscaYulita I don't know how to do it. Also, it is not part of your OP. Kindly ask a separate question for the same.

Comment: it's good to use Math.ceil instead of floor 
in floor if you try to run Math.floor(500.5/500) * 500; this you will get 500 which is wrong
but ceil will give 1000
Math.ceil(500.5/500) * 500;